# Was there an intended sequel to "Amelia, the Monkey, and the Magic Bag"?

Tags: sequel, amelia-the-monkey-and-the-magic-bag

I enjoyed reading [*Amelia, the Monkey, and the Magic Bag*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/095582270X) - it was an enjoyable read.

I was wondering if the author had ever planned to write a sequel. I cannot find anything online about a sequel, yet the book ends on a note that implies future books:

> The people from Outside are still there and getting powerful, and the Beings (I can't remember the name at the moment) had given Amelia's mother powers to use against them.

Was there an intended sequel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Peter Marsden](https://www.amazon.co.uk/PJ-Marsden/e/B0034OJ8UM) passed away in 2013. His third book ([Witch Mountain](https://www.waterstones.com/book/witch-mountain/p-j-marsden/9780955822728)) was incomplete and has not been published.

> *Peter is sadly no longer with us, but as he was one of the founding
> members of Waterside Writers, his profile has been included to honour
> his memory.*
>
> *Peter loved reading books that took him to strange places, real or
> imagined, and when he started writing he found that his pen was taking
> him far away too.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Waterside Writers Group - Profile: Peter Marsden](http://watersidewriters.net/members/peter_marsden.html)</sup></sub>

There's no indication that he was working on a sequel to Amelia, the Monkey, and the Magic Bag.

Comment: Why does the link allow one to order it, then?

Comment: @adamant - Is you click into the link, you'll see zero available copies